# Anylogic shutting down

Tags: window

I started learning Anylogic but sometimes it shuts down without asking me and I did not order to close the window.
Can anyone tell me why this is happening because I lost some of my project?

Comment: have you looked logs ?

Answer (score 0):

Anylogic has bugs, and depending on the version and your operating system, these bugs might show up and there's nothing you can do about it, only hope that in the next anylogic version, this will not happen, or maybe in your next OS update... There was a period in the past when AnyLogic was closing itself every 30 minutes for no reason for me... dark ages

Just focus on saving your work constantly, not only with auto-saving, because it's dangerous definitely, and you lose some work...

Nevertheless, when this happened to me, I started to get a feeling on when AnyLogic would close and save before... So that means with experience, this bug will affect you less and less.